Including a previously run code chunk (with the chunk options) using the `verbatim` or `embed` engines
Given a code chunk that was previously run, I would like to illustrate the code that was used to produce a desired output, with the chunk options included. For example, given a code chunk named animation-1,
```{r animation-1, fig.show='animate', animation.hook='gifski'}
for (i in seq_len(10)) {
   plot(0, i)
}
```

I would like to display this code chunk in the output document.
The verbatim engine is a solution to this problem, but requires a duplicate of animation-1, that is
````{verbatim}
```{r fig.show='animate', animation.hook='gifski'}
for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  plot(0, i)
}
```
````

An alternative is the embed engine, but requires the code to be in a separate file.
How can I reuse the existing code (named animation-1 in this example) in the a verbatim or embed chunk?
